# Html wrapper issue

Tags: apache-flex, flash, ant

My Flex application is built using ant. The html wrapper task is as follows:

```
<target name="wrapper">
    <html-wrapper 
        title="{$title}"
        file="login.htm"
        height="300"
        width="400"
        application="app"
        swf="Main.swf"
        version-major="9"
        version-minor="0"
        version-revision="0"
        history="true"
        template="express-installation"
        output="${APP_ROOT}"/>
</target>
```

My purpose is to display a message to the user in case their browser has JavaScript disabled. 
I modified the index.template.html file within the express-installation folder to include the following in the  tag:

```
<noscript><my message here/></noscript>
```

The message does not get displayed. Is there a way I could find out which index.template.html file is used by ant task or is the file being overridden somehow?

Can anyone resolve this? Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be coming from the SDK that you are using to build the wrapper. It'll be somewhere like...

```
${FLEX_HOME}/templates/express-installation/index.template.html
```

Comment: Yes, I already tested the same and had modified the index.template.html file at the location :"C:\FlexSDK\templates\express-installation" but it did not work. I am still unable to find the file it is using.

Comment: could be a bug in the Flex Ant tasks. If you do the same thing with the command line options, does it work as you'd expect?

Answer (score 1):

As of Flex SDK 4.5:

The template file used when building your project via html-wrapper ant task unfortunately does NOT come from ${FLEX_SDK_HOME}/templates/swfobject.

The template file used by the ant task is actually baked into the flexTasks.jar file found in ${FLEX_SDK_HOME}/ant/lib. As you know, there is no convenient option you can apply on the task  to use a different template.

Because my needed changes were minor (and presumably useful on all of my projects) I simply unzipped flexTasks.jar and re-zipped it with my modified template.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did use the history="true" you need change the template inside

```
P:\ath\to\sdks\X.Y.Z\templates\express-installation-with-history
```

as documented [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_7.html).